# The English Adjective

Tags: adjectives, american-english, possessives

> 1.Has an assessment been conducted to evaluate potential products impact due to this nonconformity?

---*In this sentence, is the word **POTENTIAL** describing PRODUCTS or IMPACT?*

> 2.In circumstances where the company needs to amend a permanent employees rostered day off, the employee will be provided with at least 1 week of notice

---*In this sentence, is the **PERMANENT** describing EMPLOYEES or ROSTERED DAY OFF?*

Comment: Neither of those sentences really looks completely correct, which is making it harder to interpret them.  The first one should probably be "potential products' impact", because it's something belonging to *products*.  The second one should be "a permanent employee's rostered day off", because it's something belonging to *an employee*.

Comment: All of those sentences are malformed.

Answer (score 2):

All of your sentences are slightly malformed. The first one probably should say something like this:

> Has an assessment been conducted to evaluate **the potential impact on products** due to this nonconformity?

This way, the adjective *potential* describes *impact*.

> In circumstances where the company needs to amend a permanent **employee's** rostered day off, the employee will be provided with at least one week of notice.

Notice the inserted apostrophe in *employee*. And yes, *permanent* does describe *employee*.

Comment: Thank you Mr Monster , still a little confused ~~~~(>_<)~~~~

Comment: I can see where you are coming from @CookieMonster, but sentence #1 as it was originally written could be interpreted as evaluating impact of potential products if they are talking about products in development. In which case, in my opinion, it would make more sense if it said "Has an assessment been conducted to evaluate **the** potential **product's/products'** impact due to this nonconformity? With this scenario they would possibly be assessing the impact on the user and/or end result from the use of the product